# Change Method to Assert that the Text Returned Either Contains Text entered or Equals Text Entered (C# Selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium

I have the following code:

```
   bool ColorExistsByName(string colorNameV)
    {
        var colorName = colorPage.ColorList.CategoryList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.GetText().Contains(colorNameV));
        if (colorName == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return colorName.ExistsAndDisplayed;
    }
```

I need to edit this so that it can either Contain OR Equal colorNameV... what's the best way to do this?

**EDIT**

Sorry - I wasn't clear enough. I need to somehow add a parameter (wholeWord) so that sometimes, it can use contains, and sometimes it can use equals (if we're using wholeWord) - is it possible to use parameter like this? (We already have functionality written for wholeWord parameter in order to check if wholeWord is written)

Comment: What is the tpye of colorPage?

Answer (score 0):

But your command `c.GetText().Contains(colorNameV)` does exactly what you want. If you want to test "Contains", that's what this function does. If you want to test equals, it also works, since the `c.GetText()` will **contain** `colorNameV` and nothing else (will contain just itself). It works for both of your cases.

Comment: Hi! Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I need to somehow add a parameter (wholeWord) so that sometimes, it can use contains, and sometimes it can use equals (if we're using wholeWord) - is it possible to use parameter like this? (We already have functionality written for wholeWord parameter in order to check if wholeWord is written)

Comment: You can probably use a bool "checkPartial" that if it's true, it will use contains, and if false, it will use Equals. And when you figure out (on your other functionality), that your word must equals, you will call the function with false, and when you want to check for contains, it will be true. As for how the function "ColorExistsByName" will be written, just add an if, if checkPartial, use contains, if !checkPartial, use Equals.

Comment: If it's something that you will use a lot, usually the simpler code (complexity), is the faster and easier. Even though it might not be "elegant" for some. You should change your linq to a foreach and "break;" when you find your result (since you used SingleOrDefault(), only one result). That will make your function xTimes faster.